# Is it possible to track the email sent via BCC List using firewall or network security software?

Tags: email, firewalls

I want to know whether is it possible to know the conversation/email sent via BCC can be identified by admin in some corporate companies?

I have heard that email sent from BCC cannot be identified, and I want to know how this BCC feature actually works.

Comment: Cyborgz - I have edited the post. Please don't add in the 'regards' bit, or the other pieces I will edit out. They add nothing to the question. I have also sorted grammar and spelling.

Comment: Thanks for editing the content and now it looks very crisp and clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question, depending on your setup.

If you use SSL from your PC to your mailserver (wich is not administrated by the same guys) and your connection is secure, they can't see anything about your mail, except for the size.

If you use unencrypted communication with your mailserver or the mailserver is administrated by the same guys it looks worse. They could intercept the traffic from your pc to the server and simply read the whole  request from your mailclient to the server. 
In this request there are many mail-headers including the BCC-line of the mail, so they could view each recipient's address in plain text. On wikipedia there is a really good [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP) of how such a request looks, sadly without BCC. But you can imagine the BCC line exactly like the CC line, there is no difference (except the leading 'B' of course).

Even using mail encryption (S\MIME, PGP) won't help because only the content of the mail gets encrypted, not the headers.

**Conclusion**:

The only way to send a mail without the IT-Stuff knowing the recipient is to use a third-party mailserver (like gmail, yahoo etc.) with active SSL/TLS. But even here you have to be careful: On a company-pc you might have a SSL certificate from the company installed wich allows th IT stuff to perform a man-in-the-middle attack on your communication without a security warning.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I have got some picture of how this entire mail system works at corporate firms. Those wikipedia references helps me a lot to understand quite better. Thanks Again